# Software to create a movie from picture as if it was recorded

Tags: animation, video

I am looking for a software that takes pictures (let´s say 40 of them) with some changes (for example a pregnant women that takes 1 picture per week and them creates a video from them. The goal is to show the video as it was recorded not taken pictures. The program must create all the image to complete the transition so it looks like real.

I´ve seen such a program but I can´t remember its name. I am developing a application and I want to study which features a program like that has!

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wcrkRuzg10s) I have an example.

Comment: Wouldn't `ffmpeg` work for that purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out.

Those software are called morphing software.

Here a list of them:

http://morphing-software-review.toptenreviews.com/